# Sequentially splice values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm trying to add data.addRows() positions in google.visualization.LineChart that needs multiple array of 2 values in one array, where first value need to be 0 to 127:

```
      /data.addRows([
        [0, 0], [100, 100]
        ]);
```

that results in a single line:

[image]

By creating multiple points I use google elevation along path function by generating 128 samples:

```
        elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
          'path': path,
          'samples': 128
        }, plotElevation);
      }
```

I created var samples = Array.apply(null, {length: 128}).map(function(value, index){return index + 1;}); 
where I need to splice every value I got from elevations[].elevation in multiple arrays within one array. Example:

```
data.addRows([[0,48],
              [1,59],
              [2,67],
              [3,84],
              [4,122],
              [to 127, values]
              ]);
```

I have tried for loops and nested for loops but only end up crashing my browser.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
     samples.splice(1, 0, elevations[i].elevation);
      console.log(samples);
    }
```

What would have been cool is if I could do something like this, but does not work.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
     samples[i].splice(1, 0, elevations[i].elevation);
      console.log(samples);
    }
```

All Simplified:
I have:

```
var myArray1 = [{foo: bla, bar: blabla, foobar: 111,},  //
               {foo: bla, bar: blabla, foobar: 211,},  //  128 array's of foobar values.
               ----->                                    //
               {foo: bla, bar: blabla, foobar: 999,}];  //
```

1) Need to create 1 array with 128 array within. First value in array 0 need to start 0 and last value in last array need to end on 127:

```
var myArray2 = [[0],  //first array with first value of 0
                [1],  //second array with first value of 1
                -----> 
                [127]];
```

2) Need for loops to splice in myArray1[0 - 127].foobar into second value of myArray2. End result needs to look like this:

```
var myArray2 = [[0, 111],
                [1, 211],
                -----> 
                [127, 999]];
```

Comment: Instead of returning a number (`index + 1`) just return an array `[index, <value>]`. Or did I miss something?

Comment: What is `elevations`? What is `samples`? -> Add a [mcve] that shows (a part of the) input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray1 = [[{foo: 'bla', bar: 'blabla', foobar: 111}],
                 [{foo: 'bla', bar: 'blabla', foobar: 211}],
                 [{foo: 'bla', bar: 'blabla', foobar: 999}]]

const myArray2 = myArray1.map((it, id) => [id, it[0].foobar])

display.log(JSON.stringify(myArray2)) // [[0,111],[1,211],[2,999]]
```

The format myArray1 is not specified correctly. If [[{}], [{}], [{}], .... [{}]] then the solution is at the top

Comment: myArray1 mistake corrected.
const myArray2 = myArray1.map((it, id) => [id, it[0].foobar])
console.log(myArray2); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myArray2' of undefined

Comment: ReferenceError: display is not defined

Comment: then...     const myArray2 = myArray1.map((it, id) => [id, it.foobar])